# scrapy rules do not call parsing method

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and am trying to crawl a domain, following all internal links and scraping the title of url with the pattern /example/.*

crawling works, but the scraping of the title does not since the output file is empty. Most likely I got the rules wrong. Is this the right syntax using the rules in order to achieve what I am looking for?

```
import scrapy
class BidItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
```

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from bid.items import BidItem

class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'getbid'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.domain.de/']

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(), 
            follow=True
        ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=['example/.*']), 
            callback='parse_item'
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
         href = BidItem()
         href['url']    = response.url
         href['title']  = response.css("h1::text").extract()
         return href
```

crawl: scrapy crawl getbid -o 012916.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`CrawlSpider` docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules):

> If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used,
>   according to the order they’re defined in this attribute.

Since your first rule will match all links, it will always be used and all other rules will be ignored.

Fixing the problem is as simple as switching the order of the rules.